# Why this C program display this result?

Tags: c

I'm trying to code a program to change binary string to other binary string with operator '$' '~' '|'.

But I find the result is strange.
Please tell me why result is different?

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char bstring[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1];
    int a, b;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s binary string 1 binary string 2.\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    a = stoi(argv[1]);
    b = stoi(argv[2]);

//  printf("%s\n%s\n",itos(~a,bstring),itos(~b,bstring));
//  why the result is different with next two statements?
    printf("~argument1 %s is %s.\n", argv[1], itos(~a,bstring));
    printf("~argument2 %s is %s.\n", argv[2], itos(~b,bstring));
    printf("argument1 & argument2 is %s.\n", itos(a & b, bstring));
    printf("argument1 | argument2 is %s.\n", itos(a | b, bstring));
    printf("argument1 ^ argument2 is %s.\n", itos(a ^ b, bstring));

    return 0;
}


int stoi(char *sp)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while(*sp != '\0')
    {
        sum = sum * 2 + (*sp++ - '0');
    }
    return sum;
}

char * itos(int n, char *sp)
{
    int i;
    static int size = sizeof(int) * 8;
    for(i = size - 1; i >=0; i--, n >>= 1)
    {
        sp[i] = (n & 01) + '0';
    }
    sp[size] = '\0';
    return sp;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post the text. Also explain why you think the result is strange.

Comment: The first line calls itos twice with the same string, so of course it prints the same value.

Comment: @stark You should expand that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `itos` returns the address of the buffer passed to it.

Since you pass the same buffer to both `stoi` calls in this line:

```
printf("%s\n%s\n",itos(~a,bstring),itos(~b,bstring));
```

The second call will overwrite the buffer content. `printf` then prints the same buffer (with the content written by the second call) twice, therefore you'll get the same output twice.

If you *split* the output to two different `printf` calls like this, it should work:

```
printf("%s\n", itos(~a, bstring));
printf("%s\n", itos(~b, bstring));
```

Alternatively you can use two different buffers:

```
char astring[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1];
char bstring[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1];
printf("%s\n%s\n", itos(~a, astring), itos(~b, bstring));
```